# How do I import a data set (using a roxygen directive)

Tags: r, import, dataset, roxygen2

In a "R" package that uses roxygen2, I use a built-in data set in the example code I provide.

When building and checking the package, I get

Consider adding

```
importFrom("datasets", "CO2")
importFrom("grDevices", "dev.list", "dev.off")
```

I then added the following line to my code:

```
#' @importFrom datasets CO2
```

After roxygenizing the source, NAMESPACE contains

```
importFrom(datasets,CO2)
```

However, checking the package then yields:

```
Error : object ‘CO2’ is not exported by 'namespace:datasets'
```

?CO2 tells me that CO2 resides in package:datasets.

What is going wrong here? I use R 3.3.0 and a freshly installed roxygen2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: data sets are not exported. since that package ships with r, why not simply `@import datasets` ?

Comment: I tried this, but still get `Consider adding importFrom("datasets", "CO2")` when doing R CMD check...

Comment: how are you using that data set, in an example? what if you add `data(CO2)` before working with it?

Comment: Yes, in examples. And I actually have data(CO2) as the first line of all examples.

Comment: We need to see the full roxygen block with full example, not just your copy/page/interpretation of check errors

Comment: @hrbrmstr I placed a MWE at https://gist.github.com/jsta/3fabde8c4a57bbe86aae1a41280d8674 .  I get data from `datasets::co2` but an error on `devtools::document`

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough for data within base R's datasets package, you can just assign it as itself and that'll provide the "visible binding." I found that solution [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/08/no-visible-binding-for-global-variable/) and it just worked me. For example, in the function you call the CO2 dataset, you could just use the code `CO2<- CO2` and now the check sees you have defined CO2! You could also add `@import datasets` to your function and import datasets in your DESCRIPTION file too but that would be for everything in datasets.